# check if value exists in multidimensional array and find index

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

I have an multidimensional array like this:

```
$downloadArray = [
  "downloads1" => ["downloadnaam" => "fdgssgsfg"],
  "downloads2" => ["downloadnaam" => "eyetyy"],
];
```

I need to check if the value `eyetyy` exists in this array under the key `downloadnaam`
Then I need to find the index of this value and remove it from the array.
**The expected result**:

```
$downloadArray = [
  "downloads1" => ["downloadnaam" => "fdgssgsfg"]
];
```

I tried this:

```
$index = array_search($download->name, array_column($downloadArray, 'downloadnaam'));
if ($index !== null)
{
   unset($downloadArray[$index]);
   die("found index: " . $index);
}
```

`$download->name` contains `'eyetyy'`
`$downloadArray` is my array
But it always dies and doesn't show any index on screen.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: use `array_filter`, for example: `$result = array_filter($downloadArray, function($item){
            return $item['downloadnaam'] != 'eyetyy';
        });`

Comment: The result of `array_search` will be `false` not `null` if the searched key isn't found.  Also `$index` isn't the key in the `$downloadArray`, it's the index in the `array_keys` of `$downloadArray`...

Comment: @Cositanto the value eyetyy is dynamic so its inside a variable, that doesnt work.

Comment: Your code pretty much works, with the changes I suggested - see here: https://onlinephp.io/c/600c5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working using this code

```
$downloadArray = array_filter($downloadArray, function ($item) use ($download) {
    return $item['downloadnaam'] != $download->name;
});
```

This way I don't need to find the index first.

Credits to @Cositanto

Comment: Yes, another way to do it. Just filtering items and creating a new array with them.

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way:

```php
$downloadArray = [
    "downloads1" => ["downloadnaam" => "fdgssgsfg"],
    "downloads2" => ["downloadnaam" => "eyetyy"],
];

$filter = "eyetyy";

// Search for index
$index = array_search($filter, array_column($downloadArray, "downloadnaam"));

if ($index !== false) {
    // Delete
    array_splice($downloadArray, $index, 1);
}

print_r($downloadArray);
die();
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [downloads1]    Array
        (
            [downloadnaam]    fdgssgsfg
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
$downloadArray = [
  "downloads1" => ["downloadnaam" => "fdgssgsfg"],
  "downloads2" => ["downloadnaam" => "eyetyy"],
];

foreach ($downloadArray as $subKey => $subArray) {
            if (\in_array($subArray['downloadnaam'], ['eyetyy'], true)) {
              unset($downloadArray[$subKey]);
            }
        }

var_dump($downloadArray);
```

Regards,